# I need a function that looks like this in $[-1, 1]$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm having trouble determining a function that looks like this in $[-1,1]$.
[image]
Basically, the requirements are that:

- It passes through the origin
- When $x$ is positive, it has a tiny negative slope.  Basically needs to hug the x-axis
- When $x$ is negative, it has huge negative slope, basically needs to hug the y-axis
- $x$ must exist from $-1$ to $1$.  Doesn't matter what happens beyond those points
- Function must be differentiable from $-1$ to $1$.
- Can be some crazy polynomial if needed.
- The point $(0,0)$ must be as close to a corner as possible but still differentiable.

Thanks!

Comment: What about $f(x)=e^{-x}-1$ ?

Comment: I'll try that one.  I found one that seems to work as well: $\left(x-.89\right)^{50}-.0029$

Comment: $f(x) = a\left(\frac1{x+1}-1\right)=\frac {-ax}{x+1}$ could work. Adjust $a$ depending on how much you want to hug each axis.

Comment: I'll try both, thank you!  I think e^-x could work if I multiply x by a large number

Comment: Yep, seems like e^-x is simple and works.  Produces large number when negative so I can penalize negatives properly.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{e^{-10 x}-1}{\log ^2\left(x^2\right)+10}$

Comment: Try the mirror image of the product exponential - $-xe^{-x}$.